# Getting IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python-3.x, index-error

I'm getting this index error when I run this function. This function finds the average rent  prices of a zipcode of a city. I have a dictionary of cities called city with zipcode as the key and city name as the value. There are multiple zipcodes for some cities and arrRent is a array with lists of rents of houses of the city and I want to find the average rent price.

```
def meanPrice(self, city):
    total = 0
    cityLoc = 0
    for keys, cities in self.city.items():
        if self.city[keys] == city:
            for i in self.arrRent[cityLoc]:
                total += int(self.arrRent[cityLoc][i])
            mean = total / i
            print(total / i)
        else:
            cityLoc += 1
```

Here's a snippet of the dictionary:

```
{'95129': 'San Jose'}
{'95128': 'San Jose'}
{'95054': 'Santa Clara'}
{'95051': 'Santa Clara'}
{'95050': 'Santa Clara'}
```

and here's a snippet of the array:

```
[['2659' '2623.5' '2749.5' '2826.5' '2775' '2795' '2810' '2845' '2827'
  '2847' '2854' '2897.5' '2905' '2925' '2902.5' '2869.5']

['3342.5' '3386' '3385' '3353' '3300' '3190' '3087.5' '3092' '3170'
  '3225' '3340' '3315' '3396' '3470' '3480' '3380']

['2996' '2989' '2953' '2950' '2884.5' '2829' '2785' '2908' '2850' '2761'
  '2997.5' '3020' '2952' '2997.5' '2952' '2923.5']

 ['2804.5' '2850.5' '2850' '2850' '2867' '2940' '2905' '2945' '2938'
  '2860' '2884' '2946' '2938' '2986.5' '2931.5' '3032.5']

 ['2800' '3074' '2950' '2850' '2850' '2875' '2757' '2716' '2738.5' '2696'
  '2809' '2891' '3000' '2960' '2950' '2831']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues:

1. Issue in your list 'arrRent': It is supposed to be a list of lists, containing rents. But the different rents are not separated by comma in your list:

```
      [['2659' '2623.5' '2749.5' '2826.5' '2775' '2795' '2810' '2845' '2827'
          '2847' '2854' '2897.5' '2905' '2925' '2902.5' '2869.5']

       ['3342.5' '3386' '3385' '3353' '3300' .......
```

2. Your issue in code seems to be in this block of code. i is the actual rent here, not the index:

```
    for i in self.arrRent[cityLoc]:
        total += int(self.arrRent[cityLoc][i])
```

Change it to this:

```
for i in self.arrRent[cityLoc]:
    total += int(i)
```